# The sum of cosines are given to be 'n'. The sum of its corresponding sines are to be found...

Tags: functions, trigonometry, summation, trigonometric-series

I can neither make head nor tail of this. Could anyone please show me how to solve the following problem? *"If $\sum_{i=1}^n cos \theta_i = n$ then what is the value of $\sum_{i=1}^n sin\theta_i$"?*

Comment: Did you notice that it was a sum of exactly $n$ terms?

Comment: Please edit your question...clearly both sums can not be $n$.

Comment: Can you find an example of $\cos (\theta_1)+\cos (\theta_2) =2$? What then is $\sin (\theta_1)+\sin (\theta_2) $?  How about $\cos (\theta_1)=1$ and $\sin (\theta_1)$?  Can you see a pattern?

Comment: @lulu , I have corrected the question. Sorry for the error!

Comment: @JohnHughes I have corrected the question!

Comment: My point was that you have exactly $n$ cosines, and they sum up to $n$. You need to think about that.

Comment: @JohnHughes, ah yes, if we take theta as 90 degrees, then sum of 1 term will be 1 and sin of 1 will be 0. Thanks!

Comment: When you have only $1$ equation and $n$ unknowns, you know something funny must be going on. Either the sum of sines can be gotten by rearranging the sum of cosines, or there is an inequality which forces all the cosines to a certain value, so the parameters can't actually vary. (The former turns out to not be true, so it must be the latter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \cos \theta_i = n$$ then we also have

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \cos \theta_i}n = 1$$

which means that the average cosine of these angles is $1$.

If the average cosine of these angles is $1$, what is the average sine of these angles?

> The average sine is $0$, since $\sin(\arccos 1) = 0$. Hence $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sin \theta_i}n = 0$$ which implies $\sum_{i=1}^n \sin \theta_i = 0$

Answer (score 2):

Since

$$\cos \theta_i\leq1\implies\sum_{i=1}^n \cos \theta_i \leq n$$

and equality holds if and only if

$$\forall i \quad \cos \theta_i =1\implies \sin \theta_i=0$$